# How to call canvas in View Class and change it's color from an Activity Class

Tags: java, kotlin

I have successfully implemented an Analog Clock as shown in the code below, I intend to change the color of the canvas upon pressing of a button from the MainActivity, I am stuck trying to implement this, below I have shown the View Class, the relavant XML layout and a button on ClickListener that causes the crash upon being pressed, any guidance will be really helpful.

Here is the View Class

```
public class CustomAnalogClock extends View {

    private int height, width = 0;
    private int padding = 0;
    private int fontSize = 0;
    private int numeralSpacing = 0;
    private int handTruncation, hourHandTruncation = 0;
    private int radius = 0;
    private Paint paint;
    private boolean isInit;
    private int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    private Rect rect = new Rect();
    private Canvas thecanvas;

    public CustomAnalogClock(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomAnalogClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomAnalogClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void initClock() {
        height = getHeight();
        width = getWidth();
        padding = numeralSpacing + 50;
        fontSize = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int min = Math.min(height, width);
        radius = min / 2 - padding;
        handTruncation = min / 20;
        hourHandTruncation = min / 7;
        paint = new Paint();
        isInit = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (!isInit) {
            initClock();
        }
        thecanvas = canvas;
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        drawCircle(Color.RED);
        drawCenter(canvas);
        drawNumeral(canvas);
        drawHands(canvas);
        postInvalidateDelayed(500);
        invalidate();
    }

    private void drawHand(Canvas canvas, double loc, boolean isHour) {
        double angle = Math.PI * loc / 30 - Math.PI / 2;
        int handRadius = isHour ? radius - handTruncation - hourHandTruncation : radius - handTruncation;
        canvas.drawLine(width / 2, height / 2,
                (float) (width / 2 + Math.cos(angle) * handRadius),
                (float) (height / 2 + Math.sin(angle) * handRadius),
                paint);
    }

    public void drawHands(Canvas canvas) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        float hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        hour = hour > 12 ? hour - 12 : hour;
        drawHand(canvas, (hour + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) / 60) * 5f, true);
        drawHand(canvas, c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);
        drawHand(canvas, c.get(Calendar.SECOND), false);
    }

    private void drawNumeral(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setTextSize(fontSize);
        for (int number : numbers) {
            String tmp = String.valueOf(number);
            paint.getTextBounds(tmp, 0, tmp.length(), rect);
            double angle = Math.PI / 6 * (number - 3);
            int x = (int) (width / 2 + Math.cos(angle) * radius - rect.width() / 2);
            int y = (int) (height / 2 + Math.sin(angle) * radius + rect.height() / 2);
            canvas.drawText(tmp, x, y, paint);
        }
    }

    private void drawCenter(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, 12, paint);
    }
    public void drawCircle(int color) {
        paint.reset();
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        thecanvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius + padding - 10, paint);
    }
}
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

        <kaita.stream_app_final.Activities.Modals.CustomAnalogClock
            android:id="@+id/customAnalogClockCarpte"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

WHAT DOESN'T WORK

```
change_canvas_Color.setOnClickListener {
   customAnalogClockCarpte.drawCircle(Color.GREEN)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your crash relates to the `Canvas` you're holding onto and trying to draw to? Post the crash log if it's not. I'm not sure offhand, but I think holding onto it is probably a bad idea - the general approach is to take the canvas that's passed in through `onDraw` and do all your drawing to that. I'm not sure it's valid once `onDraw` is exited.

You probably want a separate function, like:

```
public void setCircleColor(int color) {
    circlePaint.setColor(color)
    invalidate()
}
```

which updates the colour in your paint, and then forces another call to `onDraw`, which will redraw everything (including the circle with the new colour).

You *could* just store this colour value somewhere, and use it in your calls to `drawCircle` (you always pass `Color.RED` in through `onDraw()` by the way, you need to store the current colour somewhere or it'll just get painted over). But I'd really recommend you use more than one `Paint` object, and just configure each one once, instead of constantly resetting and reconfiguring a single paint to draw the different things.

That way, if you have a `circlePaint`, changing its colour is as simple as setting the colour on the paint, and that's it! Next time you draw with that paint in `drawCircle`, it'll be the right colour. No need to pass colours around or anything